# Find big theta of summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

The original algorithm is as follows

> T $\gets$ new balanced binary search tree 
>   for $i\gets 1$ to $n$ do 
>   $~~~~$ insert ary[i] into T 
>   for i $\gets$ 1 to log(n) do 
>   $~~~~$ extract the largest element from T

I know insertion into T will be $\theta(log(i))$

I know $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$ Does that mean $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(i) = \frac{\log(n)(\log(n)+1)}{2}?$$ I then can say big theta is $\theta(\log(n))$?

Comment: NO!! It means the sum $log1 +log2+...+log n=log n!$

Comment: Even assuming the absurd $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)=\frac{f(n)(1+f(n))}{2}$ for *any* function $f$, that would just imply $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)=\Theta(f(n)^{\color{red}{2}})$, hence $\log(n!)=\Theta(\log^{\color{red}{2}}(n))$.

Answer (score 2):

No, that would be an incorrect statement; however, from the properties of logarithms, you can say $$\sum_{i=1}^n\log(i)=\log(n!).$$ Now you could apply Stirling's Formula for $n!$ to get an asymptotic.